# Magento displaying price with 3 digit after decimal point

Tags: magento-1.7, price

I'm developing a magento website, prices are displaying normally. But for some prices like 9.09, magento displays 9.090.

How can i can i restrict digits to 2 after decimal point ?

Here's the code i'm using:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

and here's ow it renders:

```
<div class="price-box">
  <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-13560">
     <span class="price"> 3€<sup>090</sup></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not a default behavior. Usually people want it the other way around. Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: @Marius no extensions that impact prices.

Comment: Any javascript that might transform the prices from E3.99 to `3E<sup>99</sup>` ? The html you posted is not really standard.

Comment: May be, can it be anything else ? @Marius

Comment: I don't know. Do you have a link to your website so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this format and restrict decimal using standard php code like :

```
$numberformatted = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```